# Get cpu usage per core on the command line

Tags: macos, cpu, system-information, processor

Activity monitor allows users to see the cpu usage on a per-core basis (for multicore machines, e.g. my MacBook Pro).  Is there a way to find the percent usage of each core/processor via the command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've installed [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net) for this purpose. In order to install on OS X (10.8.4), I used [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), which installed the htop package (`brew install htop`).

Despite the fact that this is via the command line, it is still a graphical output within the terminal.

Answer (score -3):

To install htop on OS X El Capitan follow these easy steps: 
Copy and paste the following commands into a terminal window:

```
curl -O http://themainframe.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/htop.zip
unzip htop.zip
sudo mv htop /usr/local/bin
rm htop.zip
```

Run htop by entering `htop` into Terminal

Comment: There's no good reason to do that. That fork is 7 years old and fairly glitchy. htop 2 is out with proper OS X support, so just get it through brew. And make sure to install the "htop" package and not "htop-osx" (that's the same outdated fork).