# Collect data on CPU usage per core at regular time intervals?

Tags: performance, cpu, system-information, processor, statistics

Is there any easy way to get CPU usage on a per core basis at a certain interval throughout the day? (e.g. every 60 seconds)

Notes

- happy to use a script (e.g. ruby, python) and run it in the terminal
- would be great if the output were a simple csv, but open to using more sophisticated tools/outputs if they exist and are easy to use
- the ultimate goal is to take to plot a time series of per-core utilisation over the day (or week/month) (that is, a line chart with as many lines as cores)
- The answer on [Get cpu usage per core on the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94900/get-cpu-usage-per-core-on-the-command-line/) can't be used in a loop

Example output:

A csv that resembles:

```
time, core_1, core_2, core_3, core_4 (etc)
"2020-07-18 15:45:00 UTC", 15%, 12%, 0%, 1%
"2020-07-18 15:46:00 UTC", 100%, 100%, 10%, 3%
"2020-07-18 15:47:00 UTC", 10%, 2%, 0%, 0%
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that can collect this information called [glances](https://glances.readthedocs.io), which is a command line based monitoring tool that can track all sorts of parameters.

It can be installed via [homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install glances
```

You may need to tinker with the options to get something you're happy with, or parse the data downstream with a different tool, but it can output timestamped, percpu usage (in 60 second intervals) in the following way:

```
glances --stdout now,percpu --time 60
```

The results aren't quite what you outlined, but the output can be processed with other tools to get them into a format that you can use.